# Linq vs Regex split and modify a string

Tags: c#

I have a string.It looks like:

data = "DA00VB0012004500890044010000000700000004000000**010000001**0000";

data = "DA00NM0012002700890032010000000700000004000000**1A000001A**0000";

I need to split and modify that string.

Here is my code:

```
public string Getstring(string value, int start = 47, int end = 54)
{
    string spstart = string.Empty;
    string spend = string.Empty;
    start = start - 1;
    end = end + 1;
    if (value != string.Empty)
    {
        var mem = value.Substring(start, end - start);
        spstart = mem.Substring(0, 2);
        spend = mem.Substring(mem.Length - 2, 2);
    }
    if(spstart.Trim().Equals(spend.Trim())
    {
        return mem;
    }
    return "not found";
}
```

Here is the result I got:

for the first string

**01**00000**01**

the second

**1A**00000**1A**

You can see the begins and ends with the same: 01 01 or 1A 1A.

The final result I want to get:

**01**00000**01** -> **0C**00000**0C**

**1A**00000**1A** -> **0C**00000**0C**

data = "DA00VB0012004500890044010000000700000004000000**0C**00000**0C**0000";

I want to replace the beginning and ends of my string.
And then replace **01**00000**01** or **1A**00000**1A** in string with **0C**00000**0C**

I'm looking for a shorter way for Getstring and get what I want.
I'm taking a look at the Linq and the Regex.Again.
I carefully read up on them.
I won't delete this topic.I will vote up if have any solve idea.
Thank for all the helps.

Comment: please explain your output.

Comment: Since BOTH strings you are looking for... i.e. "01" are the same, how would you know when one was to be replaced with "0C" or "15"? I am guessing your second line final result should be `1A000001A -> 150000015`? If this is the case... string.substitute?

Comment: 0C and 15 are hex value.You right! second line final result.It is 1A000001A -> 150000015@JohnG

Comment: In this context they are strings... A simple string replace would solve this.

Comment: I want to know how many ways I can too :)@JohnG

Answer (score 1):

In your comment am not sure what you mean by *how many ways I can too*??? Below is how you would replace the strings as you describe. It may be better to give everyone a general ideal of what you are trying to accomplish as your question is a very simple string replace problem. Replace strings shown below.

```
  String s1 = "010000001";
  String s2 = "1A000001A";

  String s3 = s1.Replace("01", "0C");
  String s4 = s2.Replace("1A", "15");

  Console.WriteLine(s1 + " -> " + s3 + "\n\r" + s2 + " -> " + s4);
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank JohnG! using Replace It's basic way.one of the simpl. replace all the sames.as the top of topic,I'm looking for the short way for Getstring.@JohnG